# Select only observations in a df that are minimally a half year apart, starting from the last observation

Tags: r, dataframe, selection

## Introduction to my problem

I have a dataframe with unequal observations per individual and I only want to include observations that are more than a half your apart. 
 
I want to select the **last** observation per individual *first* and then select the next observation that is **minimally** a half year earlier.

### Example df

```
ID     Date        Var1 ... Var12
100    13/02/2012    x       x
100    14/09/2012    x       x
100    31/01/2013    x       x
100    18/12/2012    x       x
101    29/04/2012    x       x
102    01/11/2012    x       x
103    12/08/2012    x       x
103    22/08/2013    x       x
103    26/09/2013    x       x
103    22/01/2014    x       x
104    19/01/2012    x       x 
104    17/02/2014    x       x
104    15/03/2014    x       x
104    12/05/2015    x       x
```

The intended df should look something like this after selecting the right observations

```
ID     Date        Var1 ... Var12
100    13/02/2012    x       x
100    14/09/2012    x       x
100    18/12/2013    x       x
101    29/04/2012    x       x
102    01/11/2012    x       x
103    12/08/2012    x       x
103    22/08/2013    x       x
103    22/01/2014    x       x
104    19/01/2012    x       x 
104    17/02/2014    x       x
104    12/05/2015    x       x
```

## What I have tried

I tried to write a loop, but I was not able to deal with the selection problem.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Can you add the language/library tags so that people tracking those tags would see your question. Is this an R dataframe or Python/Pandas or maybe Spark?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I added the tag.

Comment: How big is your data (that is, how much does efficiency matter)?

Comment: Only a few thousand observations

Comment: I'm not sure your output for `ID=100` is correct. Can you verify?

Comment: You are right, there is a mistake in the last 100. Its date is from the wrong year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly, but seems to work. Load some stuff:

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)

dt <- fread("ID     Date        Var1 Var12
100    13/02/2012    x       x
100    14/09/2012    x       x
100    31/01/2013    x       x
100    18/12/2012    x       x
101    29/04/2012    x       x
102    01/11/2012    x       x
103    12/08/2012    x       x
103    22/08/2013    x       x
103    26/09/2013    x       x
103    22/01/2014    x       x
104    19/01/2012    x       x 
104    17/02/2014    x       x
104    15/03/2014    x       x
104    12/05/2015    x       x")

df <- as.data.frame(dt)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Work some `diff` magic. Note that you can change `threshold` to whatever you want here.

```
threshold <- 180
ddply(df, .(ID), function(x) {
    x <- x[order(x[,2], decreasing=T),]
    sel <- diff(x[,2]) < -threshold
    sel2 <- diff(x[,2])
    sel2[!sel] <- cumsum(as.numeric(diff(x[,2])))[!sel]

    x[c(1,which(sel2 < -threshold)+1),]
})
```

The ugly mess of `diff` and `cumsum` does the following for each `ID`:

- Sort by Date in descending order
- Compute the date difference between observations, and mark which ones exceed `threshold`
- Replace date difference with cumulative sum for observations that aren't marked
- Grab the ones that are now marked

And voila

```
    ID       Date Var1 Var12
1  100 2013-01-31    x     x
2  100 2012-02-13    x     x
3  101 2012-04-29    x     x
4  102 2012-11-01    x     x
5  103 2014-01-22    x     x
6  103 2012-08-12    x     x
7  104 2015-05-12    x     x
8  104 2014-03-15    x     x
9  104 2014-02-17    x     x
10 104 2012-01-19    x     x
```